# Включен ли у пользователя ночной режим в браузере

Tags: javascript, css

Как узнать включен ли у пользователя в браузере ночной (темный) режим?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

Comment: Спасибо, то, что надо)